Handling Short Plaintexts in Format-Preserving Encryption: A Challenge with FF3 Algorithm Minimum Length Requirements
I've developed a Python program that performs format-preserving encryption (FPE) for all data types, including numeric, alphanumeric, and alphabetic. It ensures that the data type (alpha or numeric) and the case (upper or lower) are preserved. For example, "Hdcj213" might be encrypted as something like "Bcdg980."
The challenge I'm facing is with data that falls below the minimum length required for FF3 (the FPE algorithm). For numeric data, the minimum length is 6 digits, so I can't encrypt and preserve the format of something like "492." For alphabetic data, the minimum is 4 characters.
Padding is not a viable solution because it disrupts the format, and the goal is to preserve the format after encryption.
Is there a solution for handling short plaintexts?

"and if you post a related question, make sure you link to your previous question and identify the differences.". Apparently it doesn't register with you when something is said once, so here it is again. I don't care at all what you think about me at this time or whenever. And yeah, the fact that you cannot FF3 encrypt a shorter plaintext without running into issues is a fundamental problem with the tech, so I don't think you'll find a trick around it on a development Q/A site. You could try and combine two fields and get a bigger one, but that does have downsides.

This question on the [crypto.se] site probably is the question you are asking. However, it doesn't have any answers yet.
